# Why command generate:doctrine:entities don't generate methods in these classes? (reverse engineering)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

(I'm a beginner)

I would like to automatically generate methods for related models (OneToMany and ManyToOne). Im doing it following  docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

I added following properties and annotations to the models (I give here only two classes related by ManyToOne as a example) and run generate:doctrine:entities command with no errors and no results. I expected methods like __construct and addXXX() in Kategoria class with OnoToMany relation.

This is fragment I added to Kategoria class.

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ksiazka", mappedBy="kategoria")
*/
protected $ksiazki;
```

This is entire Kategoria class with OneToMany relation.

```
#Kategoria.php 
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Kategoria
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="kategoria")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Kategoria
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nazwa", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nazwa;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idKategoria", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idkategoria;

   #THESE NEXT 4 LINES I ADDED
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ksiazka", mappedBy="kategoria")
    */
    protected $ksiazki;

    /**
     * Set nazwa
     *
     * @param string $nazwa
     * @return Kategoria
     */
    public function setNazwa($nazwa)
    {
        $this->nazwa = $nazwa;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nazwa
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNazwa()
    {
        return $this->nazwa;
    }

    /**
     * Get idkategoria
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdkategoria()
    {
        return $this->idkategoria;
    }
}
```

This is a fragment I modified in Ksiazka class. I added `, inversedBy="ksiazki"`

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria", inversedBy="ksiazki")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idKategoria", referencedColumnName="idKategoria")
 * })
 */
private $idkategoria;
```

This is entire Ksiazka class with ManyToOne relation.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ksiazka
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ksiazka", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idKategoria_idx", columns={"idKategoria"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ksiazka
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="autor", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $autor;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="opis", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $opis;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cena", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cena;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="obrazek", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $obrazek;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="wydawnictwo", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $wydawnictwo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rokWydania", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $rokwydania;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="string", length=45)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $isbn;

//    Było. Automatycznie wygenerowane bez inversedBy.
//    /**
//     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria
//     *
//     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria")
//     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
//     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idKategoria", referencedColumnName="idKategoria")
//     * })
//     */
//    private $idkategoria;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria", inversedBy="ksiazki")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idKategoria", referencedColumnName="idKategoria")
     * })
     */
    private $idkategoria;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Zamowienie_Produkt", mappedBy="ksiazka")
    */
    protected $zamowienie_produkty;


    /**
     * Set autor
     *
     * @param string $autor
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setAutor($autor)
    {
        $this->autor = $autor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get autor
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAutor()
    {
        return $this->autor;
    }

    /**
     * Set opis
     *
     * @param string $opis
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setOpis($opis)
    {
        $this->opis = $opis;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get opis
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getOpis()
    {
        return $this->opis;
    }

    /**
     * Set cena
     *
     * @param string $cena
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setCena($cena)
    {
        $this->cena = $cena;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cena
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCena()
    {
        return $this->cena;
    }

    /**
     * Set obrazek
     *
     * @param string $obrazek
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setObrazek($obrazek)
    {
        $this->obrazek = $obrazek;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get obrazek
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getObrazek()
    {
        return $this->obrazek;
    }

    /**
     * Set wydawnictwo
     *
     * @param string $wydawnictwo
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setWydawnictwo($wydawnictwo)
    {
        $this->wydawnictwo = $wydawnictwo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wydawnictwo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getWydawnictwo()
    {
        return $this->wydawnictwo;
    }

    /**
     * Set rokwydania
     *
     * @param string $rokwydania
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setRokwydania($rokwydania)
    {
        $this->rokwydania = $rokwydania;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rokwydania
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRokwydania()
    {
        return $this->rokwydania;
    }

    /**
     * Get isbn
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIsbn()
    {
        return $this->isbn;
    }

    /**
     * Set idkategoria
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria $idkategoria
     * @return Ksiazka
     */
    public function setIdkategoria(\AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria $idkategoria = null)
    {
        $this->idkategoria = $idkategoria;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idkategoria
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria 
     */
    public function getIdkategoria()
    {
        return $this->idkategoria;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all methods in Entity class. Then run doctrine:generate:entities command. If not help, try to find mapping errors in profiler. Hope it help.